# 2 Sub-limits of sequence converge epsilon proof

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

consider $\left(a_n\right)_{n=0}^{\infty }$, $L_1,L_2\:\in \mathbb{R}$.
$\lim _{k\to \infty }\left(a_{2k}\right)\:=\:L_1$, $\lim _{k\to \infty }\left(a_{2k-1}\right)\:=\:L_2$ .
How to prove using limit-of-sequence definitions (using $\epsilon $ and stuff..and without any other useful sentences) that if $L_1=L_2$, then
$\left(a_n\right)_{n=0}^{\infty }$ converges.

So far i wrote this:
By the limit definition, we know that $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists N_0\:\forall n>N_0\:\rightarrow \:\left|a_{2n}\:-\:L_1\right|<\epsilon $ and $\exists N_1\:\forall n>N_1\:\rightarrow \:\left|a_{2n-1}\:-\:L_2\right|<\epsilon $.
I need to show that for any $\epsilon $ $\exists N_{ }\:\forall n>N_{ }\:\rightarrow \:\left|a_n\:-\:L_1\left(=L_2\right)\right|<\epsilon $ .I think i need to check if n is odd or even but i don't know how to continue from here. can someone guide me?

Comment: Can you find a number $N$ which is at least as big as both $N_0$ and $N_1$?  That would work for both.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang correct, i choose $N\:=\:max\left\{N_0,N_1\right\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $N=\max\{N_1N_2\}$. Then for any $n>N$, if $n$ is even, $$|a_n-L_1|< \varepsilon$$ and if $n$ is odd $$ |a_n-L_2|< \varepsilon.$$ Since $L_1=L_2$, you can conclude that for any $n>N$, $$ |a_n-L|< \varepsilon,$$ where $L=L_1=L_2$. Thus $a_n\to L$.